# Writable file permission problems

Tags: java, windows

In a project I'm working on in Windows 7, using JDK 7u25, I have a class that stores the state for the application. That class has a static `save` method to save the state to disk. I originally had the following code. (`state` is a `JSONObject` and I'm assuming that the output directory hasn't necessarily been created when this function is called.)

```
public State {
    private static String stateFile = "\\state\\state.json";

    public static void save() {
        try {
            File sFile = new File(stateFile);
            sFile.mkdirs();
            sFile.setWritable(true);
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(sFile);
            String str = state.toString(4);
            file.write(str);
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            HLogger.log(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I ran this code, it logged an IOException - complaining that access to the state file was denied. I discovered that if I changed the `save` function (as shown below) it would work exactly as expected.

```
    public static void save() {
        try {
            File sFile = new File(stateFile);
            File path = new File(sFile.getParent());
            path.mkdirs();
            sFile.setWritable(true);
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(sFile);
            String str = state.toString(4);
            file.write(str);
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            HLogger.log(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain why it's necessary to create the output directory in a separate file object in order to obtain write permission for the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not permissions failure but is a misuse of `FileWriter`.

In the first code snippet a directory named `state.json` is being created by the call to [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) because it:

> **Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories.** Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

and then an attempt to write to the directory using a `FileWriter` is made, which fails. The following is the `throws` clause From [`FileWriter(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File%29):

> `IOException` - **if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file**, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

The second snippet creates a directory named `state` (because it is using the parent of `\\state\\state.json`) and then a file named `state.json`, and therefore uses `FileWriter` on a regular file which succeeds.

Comment: Ah. That makes perfect sense. Thanks!